# Changing Size and X and Y coordinates of SVG to place ontop of another SVG C#

Tags: c#, svg

I am using the [SVG NuGet Package](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) to try and add around 10 other SVG's ontop of the root SVG, whilst scaling the 10 and then positioning them in static places.

I have the static values defined, however when i apply them to the Child element before they are added it doesn't work, which I completely understand why, as I am changing that SVG and not the SVG they are being added too.

What I need to do, is Add the SVG's to the Root SVG and then change their size and X and Y coordinates.

Does anyone know how this would be accomplished?

Where I currently assign the psoition and size values too

```
private SvgDocument StyleCharacter(Characters character, float rootHeight, float rootWidth, Positioner position)
    {
        // Scale Character
        SvgDocument newCharacter = AdjustSize(character, rootHeight, rootWidth);
        // Position Character
        newCharacter.X = position.X;
        newCharacter.Y = position.Y;
        // Add Character to Root
        return newCharacter;
    }
```

Where I am adding the SVG's to the Root.

```
private SvgDocument AddToRoot(int noOfPositionsLeft, int noOfPositionsRight, List<Characters> Left, List<Characters> Right)
    {
        List<Positioner> leftPositions = GetPositions(false);
        List<Positioner> rightPositions = GetPositions(true);
        SvgDocument root = SvgDocument.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Resources/road2.svg");
        float rootHeight = root.Height.Value;
        float rootWidth = root.Width.Value;
        // For Each Position
        for (int count = 0; count < noOfPositionsLeft; count++)
        {
            root.Children.AddAndForceUniqueID(StyleCharacter(Left[count], rootHeight, rootWidth, leftPositions[count]));

        }
        for (int count = 0; count < noOfPositionsRight; count++)
        {
            root.Children.Add(StyleCharacter(Right[count], rootHeight, rootWidth, rightPositions[count]));
        }
        return root;
    }
```

[Please see the link to Dropbox where three assets are available, the Road is the Root](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t9xdmm3ae2qsogt/AABoCN8C-LaGNM6HWyY_2Onua?dl=0)

Comment: SVG is xml format5 and any technique using XML will work.  You do not need a thrid party app to parse file.  SVG files are usually huge so best method is to use XmlReader class in Net Library.  I wold need sample of your SVG to help.

Comment: @jdweng I have provides assets for you :)

Comment: I will look at it later today.  A SVG contains layers and you have to be careful to make sure you are adding/modifying the correct layer.  You may have a map where the layers are the altitude, roads, vegetation, waterways.,

Comment: See if following helps : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100464/how-to-join-multiple-path-objects-into-a-combined-path-object-in-inkscape?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I'm afraid i need this to be automated so using Inkscape isn't really possible. If you are refering to the process of joining the items in a union, maybe however I am more concerned about modifying the sizes, unless i'm misinterpreting what you are providing.

Comment: There is really two steps in this task.  First create the union.  Then position the items.  Your xml files were created with inkscape and that is why I gave the link.  I would like to see a sample of you xml files joined with inkscape.  I can then take your three and combined them in code.  The hard part is to automatically position the three objects.  Once I see the combined file I will have a clue on how to position items.

Comment: @jdweng please see two examples in the Dropbox of what the system produces at the moment. Also be aware that there is a bug that is adding both types of arrows (still not sure why that's happening but it's irrelevant to this question)

Comment: I know what needs to be done and can do it without the library.  Not sure exactly how to accomplish in the library.  Basically you need to create a new SVG and then add paths to the new SVG which are the old SVG documents.

Comment: I downloaded code from Nuget.  Looking at some of the source code found following file : MarkerEndTest.cs.  I think the code you need is in this file.

Comment: @jdweng I see what you mean. Good spot! I am working on this project tommorow afternoon and over the weekend so I will get back to you how it goes. If it works, please post it as an answer.

Comment: I got the Nuget project compiled so I can help if you can't figure out the solution.

Comment: This is incredibly complex. I am not sure how to get any of this working in my code as each asset is already developed and just needs adding and positioning, whereas this code seems to draw each item individually. I am begining to wonder whether to take my assets, and scale them to fit in the correct place of the scene, then add them to the scene depending on where they should go. A little more Inkscape work but easier to develop, especially when I'm under time pressure to get it running asap.

Comment: The position (scaling) is the issue.  Do you want each image on its own layer or do you want all images on the same layer?  First you need to import all the images and then open the xml file as text and verify you put the images into the xml correctly.  Then move the images.  There are some tools on the internet to help move images.  If the scaling is correct all you need to do is to move the start position of each image (upper left corner).   I would start by using xml linq to get the position of each image and put into a GUI.  Then manual change position in GUI and then write back to xml.

Comment: Really sorry @jdweng, I decided to switch to PNG this evening and instantly worked like a charm so I won't be persuing the SVG situation anymore. Thank you so much for all your help, you've been brilliant!

Comment: I ran the test program SVGViewer.  Fixed one line of code in SvgViewBox.cs : if (coords.Length < 4) (was = 4) and got all three of your SVG files to run. Only one actually displayed in the tool, but it did create a output.png file with the image.  The viewer does a combine but results are probably overlayed so you can't see all the images.